# Create a table based on a ledger

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Give a ledger-like set of data with 3 columns:

```
Name,Type,Amount
Foo,A,-100
Bar,A,-200
Baz,A,-500
Foo,B1,200
Foo,A,-100
Bar,A,-300
Baz,B2,2000
Bar,A,-300
```

If I want to make a table that has these headers:

```
Name,X,Y,Z
```

where `Name` is a distinct list of `Name` in the first table,

where `X` is sum of the values from the first table where `Name`s match, `Type` is `A`, and `Value` is negative

where `Y` is the sum of values from the first table where `Name`s match, `Type` starts with `B`, and `Value` is positive

where `Z` is `Y / X`

How might I do this?
Right now I have this implemented as 2 different queries for `X` and `Y`, but they repeat the `Name` column, and it's not combine-able into `Z` because those two queries don't return the same set of `Names` since some `Names` don't have any values that match the query for both `X` and `Y`.

Here's a concrete example in a sheet I made:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbwLqRncgo8pQNU4oAeYfEHr5o4L8EGB-Skhu869fGE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can help you solve this without too much trouble, but it's tough in the abstract.  Could you paste some fake data into a new sheet and share it as an editable link so that I and others can demo / test solutions?

Comment: Please add a desired result example, it would help too.

Comment: Thanks, just added it to the question!

Comment: Please make your sheet shared and editable by all - we need to be able to update it, so make sure it is only a copy of your sheet, and with non sensitive data.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to do that. Now everyone should be able to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.

I added a tab to your sheet, Sheet1-GK.  In it, I first calculate the amounts that are either distributed, or invested, for each row of your data - see formulas in cells D1 and E1.  Then I use the following query, in G8, to produce the result that you were asking for.

```
=query(A1:E12,"select A, sum(D), sum(E), sum(E)/sum(D) group by A label sum(D) ' Invested', sum(E) 'Distributed', sum(E)/sum(D) 'MoM'",1)
```

The only issue is having the MoM value return as negative.  This could be handled with another column, if necessary, to force the absolute value.  I'm not sure if there is any way to incorporate that in the query statement.

Let me know if this is useful, or if you need something different.

[image]